# Harmonics of an infinite cylinder

Tags: acoustics, frequency

If a hypothetical cylinder was infinitely long, could it vibrate at any frequency, since any frequency would be a harmonic of it? And (less hypothetically) if a cylinder was only really long, would it have a similar effect?

I'm talking specifically about sound waves (and more specifically, trumpets).

Comment: The usual construction is to solve the problem on a bounded cylinder of length $L$ and then take the $\lim_{L \to \infty}$.

Comment: @dmckee The problem with that approach is that the limit of v/2L (or v/4l) as L approaches infinity is zero.

Comment: That's not a problem. It is the answer to your question.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm off. v/2l would be undefined. Although I don't think my original question was clear enough.